# Popup that contains feature type details from geoserver

Tags: geoserver, web-mapping, openlayers-2, popup

I would like to seek for help regarding my project. I'm new in Web Mapping. And as of now I have WMS layer (which is polygon type) from geoserver that is overlayed in a WMS openlayers basemap.

Now I would like to have an interaction, a popup to be specific, that displays the feature type details that is from the geoserver. Also before that the user could highlight the selected polygon or feature.

Please enlighten me on what first to prepare and what next to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/WMSGetFeatureInfo-js.html). This would allow you to capture a click event and use it to poll the WMS endpoint for that specific feature's properties.

For highlighting the feature, you might want to consider pulling WFS/vector tiles and rendering them on top of the WMS layer. Using the hover method to pull the currently selected (via mouseover) feature might end up being a lot of overhead/network traffic.

Also, you should confirm (via QGIS) that the WMS is returning the feature properties you desire. Make sure the WMS is properly configured before you try hooking up OpenLayers and finding you're not receiving any attribute data.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the helpful tip! :) could post example links that can help me, like on how to confirm via QGIS that the WMS  is returning the feature properties you desire. thank you!

Comment: So, if you use the Layer Preview functionality from within GeoServer, you should be able to view an OpenLayers map preview of the layer. Clicking on the map should show a record set below the map with attributes. For example, [here's what it looks like using the GeoServer demo server.](http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/usgs/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=usgs:tracts&styles=&bbox=-79.036352,37.828556999999996,-75.766667,39.723005&width=569&height=330&srs=EPSG:4269&format=application/openlayers) You can view source and see how it works. (1/2)

Comment: If you take that same URL and pass it into QGIS, you should be able to load the selected layer into QGIS and confirm that the attributes appear the correct way. You may also want to explore some of the ways the [WMS service can inform you on what it provides via "GetCapabilities".](https://wiki.state.ma.us/confluence/display/massgis/GeoServer+-+WMS+-+GetCapabilities) (2/2)